# How to prevent Nginx encoding rewritten uri?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have the following nginx.conf:

```
rewrite ^ $args?;
rewrite url=(.*) "$1" break;
proxy_pass http://proxy_backend;
```

The resulting $1 is some URL similar to `https://google.com/?arg=value`, which I want to be passed to proxy_backend **as is**. However nginx seems to be passing `GET https://google.com/%3Farg=value`. How can I prevent it from encoding the question mark?

Comment: That depends on what rewrite rule you are actually using; unless you show what it actually is, it won't be possible to answer your question.

Comment: This doesn't helps any further. The `url=(.*)` assumed to be a regex upon a normalized URI should be match; do you now what the **normalized URI** actually is? If you don't, check the [`location`](https://nginx.org/r/location) directive documentation. In any case it doesn't include the query part of the request URI.

Comment: In a previous step the url was rewritten to the query string; then part of the query string was extracted to be the new url. The query string is `?url=https://google.com/?arg=value` (un-encoded when passed).

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can try `rewrite url=(.*?)(?:%3F(.*))? $1?$2? break;`